# How to pass multiple parameters to INSERT INTO ... VALUES using SQLAlchemy Connection.execute()?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, parameter-passing

The following is valid SQL for PostgreSQL.

```sql
INSERT INTO schema.table (id, letter)
VALUES 
    (1, 'a'),
    (2, 'b'),
    ...
```

I would like to execute a similar, parameterized statement using SQLAlchemy. I am using SQLAlchemy 1.4* `Connection.execute()`, but I do not have access to the table mapper class (ORM model).

The following *does not work*, but does demonstrate what I am trying to achieve.

```py
statement: str = """
    INSERT INTO schema.table (id, letter)
    VALUES :values
"""

values: Tuple[Tuple[int, str], ...] = (
    (1, "a"),
    (2, "b"),
)

with engine.connect() as connection:
    connection.execute(
        sqlalchemy.text(statement),
        {"values": values},
    )
```

In this exact example, `values` is a tuple; it gets bound as a tuple of tuples, which does not fit what I am trying to achieve ("INSERT has more expressions than target columns"). Likewise, using a list of tuples creates a SQL `ARRAY`.

> Q: *Why don't you just use an f-string or `"...".format(...)`?*

> A: I've read that this is poor practice.

**Question:** How can I properly "unpack" the `values` parameters? Alternatively, what is the best way to achieve what I am seeking (without using the `Table` ORM class)?

---

* Yes, I am aware that SQLAlchemy 1.4 is deprecated at the time of this question's posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following, you were almost there, you just had to change the insert query and make the binding as a list of dicts.

As seen in the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/dbapi_transactions.html#sending-multiple-parameters)
and slightly modified for your use-case.

```
statement: str = "INSERT INTO schema.table (id, letter) VALUES (:id, :letter)"

values = (
    (1, "a"),
    (2, "b"),
)

values = [{'id': id, 'letter': letter} for id, letter in values]

with engine.connect() as connection:
    connection.execute(text(statement), values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dictionaries seems to work but I think the more correct version uses `insert().values()` and a `Table` object.  Are you not able to generate the `Table` object?

```py
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    stmt = text("INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES(:id, :name)")
    conn.execute(stmt, [dict(id=1, name="test"), dict(id=2, name="testagain")])
```